# Make Container Expand With Wide Table Beyond Browser Viewport

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a container, with a table inside. The table has so much content that it expands beyond the browser viewport, causing a horizontal scroll bar. **This is actually fine**.

The challenge is: while the table expands beyond the viewport, the table's container does **not**. **How do I get the table's container to expand beyond the viewport along with the table?**

Here's the basic example code (also in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/joelbyrd/pen/ROBOZx)):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>column 1 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 2 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 3 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 4 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 5 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 6 really long heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either set the container to have `position: absolute` or you can set it to have `overflow-x: scroll`. `position: absolute` will make the border stretch the entire width of the container, so the entire webpage can be scrolled with a continuous border, while `overflow-x: scroll` will create the scrollbar in the actual container, rather than the webpage, and put the border around the container.

`position: absolute`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>column 1 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 2 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 3 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 4 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 5 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 6 really long heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

`overflow-x: scroll`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>column 1 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 2 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 3 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 4 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 5 really long heading</th>
        <th>column 6 really long heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the table's container to expand beyond the viewport along with the table?

Try expressing the `container` `width` as pixels, inches, etc. in your CSS.